# Cannot access directory via SFTP - "locked"-Flag

Tags: chmod

I'am trying to access a remote Directory via SFTP. 
`ls` in the parent dir says that where the `d` for directory should be, there is an `l`. Manpage of chmod says something about "mandatory locking", but there's no hint how to remove the lock.

```
lrwxrwxrwx    0 1000     1100         193B Mar 17  2011 JWF4nwWqm85-TnsJ57hObvO7rrjOJmmlRSfd4ohb65Ct30
```

I haven't got any root-priviledges, nor any shell access (except SFTP) on that server. The file was created with the exact same user as I am using right now.

How to access that directory / remove that locked flag?

**Edit**

Error message accessing that file is `Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory`. But `ls` says it is there.

Answer (score 0):

If this output is taken from `ls -l`, the first `l` in the output means this is a symbolic link not a locked file. Under bash, you will get also something

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 khaled khaled     7 2012-01-23 12:01 temp -> /tmp/temp
```

This tells you that the file temp in current directory is a symlink to a file in `/tmp`.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. And how to copy that symlink via SFTP without getting an error?

Comment: Did you post the exact error message?

Comment: Edited the post and added the error message

Comment: @k_wave: It seems that the symlink is invalid (the original file has been removed).

Comment: Of course it is invalid. That symlink was copied to the server, but the file it is pointing to was not. My question is how to download ONLY the symlink (not it's destination)?